# Is a function in a for loop declaration will be called for many times in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, time-complexity

There is a function and a for loop:

```
def helper():
    return [1,2,3]

for i in helper():
    print(i)
```

I am wondering if the helper function would only be called once at the initialization of the for loop. As I am thinking that if I call the function and assign the return array to a variable in advance, which would be used in the for loop like this:

```
def helper():
    return [1,2,3]
temp = helper()
for i in temp:
    print(i)
```

Is that with less time complexity?

Thanks!

Comment: No, that is pretty much the same thing, except your first example doesn't need the temp variable so looks cleaner, easier to read etc. If you are ever unsure about things like this, just put print statements in your code to see what's happening.

Comment: It is only evaluated once

Comment: You could test this yourself by printing a message in `helper()`, and seeing if that message gets printed once, or more than once.

Comment: Yeah, adding some so-simple-it’s-a-no-brainer `print` statements is all you need to go from `wondering` To `knowing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the yield operation:

```
def helper():
    for i in [1,2,3]:
         yield i

for i in helper():
    print(i)
```

in this case the `helper()` method would return the `i` value during each iteration to the calling `for` loop.